# Firestore delete / set not working after phone screen is off / locked

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have two simple buttons. One is add to cart, the other is remove from cart. I am also using Provider to keep track of the quantity for each product. Everything is working fine except when testing on a phone and the phone is off / locked for a longer period. After opening and tapping the buttons nothing happens. Any ideas? Is there anything wrong with this?

pubspec.yaml

I just upgraded to `provider: ^4.3.2+3` and will test

```
provider: ^4.1.2
```

Provider map:

```
  Map _cartIDSMap = {};
  Map get cartIDSMap => _cartIDSMap;
  set cartIDSMap(Map newValue) {
    _cartIDSMap = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Buttons:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CartController _cartController = CartController();
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    Content content = Provider.of<Content>(context);

 Widget _addRemoveButtons() {
      return content.cartIDSMap[widget.food.code] != null
          ? CircleAvatar(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                onPressed: () {
                  _cartController
                      .removeFoodFromCart(widget.food.code, user.uid)
                      .then((data) {
                    if (data) {
                      setState(() {
                        content.cartIDSMap.removeWhere(
                            (key, value) => key == widget.food.code);
                        _showToast("Removed from cart");
                      });
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          : ... add button
    }
```

CartController:

```
  Future removeFoodFromCart(code, uid) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference _ref = _db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('cart')
          .doc(code.toString());

      await _ref.delete();
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      return err;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that apps don't appear to run while the screen is off is a feature of the device, not a problem of the app.  When the screen is off, the operating system will soon shut down network access to applications in order to save battery and network bandwidth, in order for the user to avoid surprises.  In general, you should not expect an app to run normally while it's on screen.

Different operating systems and app frameworks provide special ways for apps to schedule background work.  Look into those options and pick something that might suit your use case.  It will likely require a fair amount of work to integrate into that system.